# Roles and read only fields in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, roles, user-roles

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. We have an entity with a "password" field. This field appears as a MD5 hash. Most users can manually modify this MD5 hash. Some other cannot. I can't find the setting specifying what users can edit this field.

I tried modifying the security roles to align it to a person who can edit the field but it doesn't seem to have any effect on that person. Maybe this is handled at user group level ? I can't find it there either.

Maybe this is coded in a JS script, but I don't find it. Maybe it's done simply in the UI without any script.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you are dealing with. I'd suggest a simple workaround to exclude scripting and form stuff from your list: Just create a new Form and add the field in question. Any Form or Scripting related stuff will be out of the game then. Proceed to check Field Security Profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Check Field Security Profiles.

Check if any JavaScript has been added to the CRM form.